# 500 Internal server error em arquivos PHP

Tags: php, apache

Toda vez que executo um arquivo PHP no servidor ele retorna (no header) um erro 500.
Isso só acontece com arquivos PHP...

Comandos como `echo` e `phpinfo()` só com strings funcionam (testei com `echo 'teste';`). Mas se eu passo a usar códigos mais complexos, tipo incluir arrays e etc, ele já não funciona e da aquele erro.

Pensei que poderia ser um erro no meu script, mas funciona em `localhost`...

A saida para `ls -l` nas pasta `public_html` é a seguinte:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan 28 06:50 app
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 28 06:50 css
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 28 06:50 fonts
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jan 28 06:52 img
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  859 Jan 28 06:50 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 28 06:52 js
```

Desde já, obrigado.

@Edit:

Segue meu script completo.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/*
 *  0 = confirmado
 *  1 = talvez
 *  2 = não vai
 */

$convidados = [
    'Cieli' => [0,15],
    'Carlinhos' => [0,30],
    'Daianna' => [1,0],
    'Renato' => [0,20],
    'Ana' => [3,0],
    'Larissa' => [0,20],
    'Debora' => [0,30],
    'Dani' => [0,0],
    'Suelen' => [1,0],
    'Vitor' => [1,0],
    'Felipe' => [1,0],
    'Luany' => [1,0],
    'Sandra' => [1,0],
    'Halysson' => [1,0],
    'Karina' => [3,0],
    'Mariana' => [3,0],
    'Wanessa' => [0,30],
    'Matheus' => [1,20],
    'Mauricio' => [3,0],
    'Mayara' => [1,20],
    'Lukas' => [1,0],
    'Leticia' => [1,0],
    'Geord' => [1,0],
    'Zé' => [3,0],
    'Luana' => [1,0],
    'Keity' => [0,20],
    'Werinton' => [0,20]
];

ksort($convidados);

$confirmed       = '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>';
$not_confirmed   = '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>';
$awaiting        = '<i class="fa fa-circle"></i>';
$total           = [];
$total_confirmed = 0;

foreach ($convidados as $key => $value) {
    $total[] = $convidados[$key][1];

    if( $convidados[$key][0] === 0 ) {
        $total_confirmed += 1;
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Site</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <h2>
                Site
            </h2>
        </header>

        <main role="main" class="main-width">
            <h3>Tabela de confirmados</h3>

            <table>
                <caption>
                    Legenda: (<?php echo $confirmed; ?>) Confirmado, (<?php echo $awaiting; ?>) Aguardando confirmação, (<?php echo $not_confirmed; ?>) Não confirmado
                </caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Convidado</td>
                        <td>Confirmado</td>
                        <td>Valor</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                    foreach ($convidados as $key => $value) {
                        echo 
                            '
                            <tr>
                                <td>' . $key . '</td>
                                <td>' . ($convidados[$key][0] === 0 ? $confirmed : ($convidados[$key][0] === 1 ? $awaiting : $not_confirmed)) . '</td>
                                <td>R$' . number_format($convidados[$key][1], 2, ',', '.') . '</td>
                            </tr>
                            ';
                    }
                ?>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">Total de confirmados: <?php echo $total_confirmed; ?></td>
                        <td colspan="1">Total arrecadado: R$<?php echo number_format(array_sum($total), 2, ',', '.'); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </main>

        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No seus arquivos de teste, adicione essas duas linhas para exibir os erros no host de produção: `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Tela em branco ou erro 500 é certeza de erro no código.

Comment: Já estava usando... Veja o script acima; Não seria erro no código tentei criar um array e dar um echo nele através do indice, o que funciona em localhost, mas no server não funciona.

Comment: Apareceu o erro? qual a versão do php dos dois servidores?

Comment: Não, nenhum erro. No site, fica a página em branco, em localhost, funciona perfeito. A versão do localhost é 5.5.9, e no site é 5.3.3

Comment: Já verificou os logs do apache? Existe algum error_log no diretório atual do script?

Comment: Sabe me dizer onde fica o diretório de logs? O servidor usar o Centos...

Comment: Logs no CentOS fica no `/var/logs/httpd`. Acredito que possa ser um erro no CGI, se você estiver usando CGI.

Comment: Tem uma porrada de logs de erros, a maioria ou relacionada a arquivos não encontrados (provavelmente de testes de scripts), outros em relação a função Date(), uma log mais antiga com isso "script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/test-cgi" e a mais recente relacionada ao CGI é essa: "client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /tmUnblock.cgi"

Answer (score 2):

A [sintaxe abreviada de arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) está disponável a partir do php5.4, como o seu host de produção utiliza uma versão inferior(5.3.3) comparada ao localhost(5.5.9) o seguinte erro é gerado:

> syntax error, unexpected '[' in

Para corrigir isso é necessário converter para a sintaxe antiga, isso pode ser com um replace da sua IDE/editor de texto copie o trecho do array, depois substitua `[` por `array(` e `]` por `)` não esqueça de `$total` quem também é um array.

Sintaxe php5.4

```
$convidados = [
    'Cieli' => [0,15],
    'Carlinhos' => [0,30]
];
```

Sintaxe para versões anteriores:

```
$convidados = array(
    'Cieli' => array(0,15),
    'Carlinhos' => array(0,30)
);
```

No [exemplo(sandbox)](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a633aee955c2eaaab411ddab503f1a0cbc3302ae) é possível executar o código em diferentes versões do php. Veja seu código convertido rodando no [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/p9bm-p1g8) onde a versão do php é a 5.3.29.

Comment: Também pensei que pudesse ser isso. E inclusive já realizei os testes com essa sintaxe. Mas ainda continuo recebendo este erro no console... Veja uma screenshot do console: http://i.imgur.com/L6nwCuD.png
(+1 Pela dica do array, não sabia..)