# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')' fuciona local, mas não no Servidor

Tags: php

Bom dia,

O codigo abaixo funciona local, mas quando upei deu o seguinte erro

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')' in D:\Inetpub\vhosts\....."caminho do arquivo)
```

Codigo do erro:

```
$conn = getConnection();
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT senha, usuario FROM usuario where usuario.usuario = :cnpj');
$stmt->execute(['cnpj' => $cnpj]);
$resultado = $stmt->fetch();
$usuario = $resultado['usuario'];
$senha = $resultado['senha'];
```

Comment: Usa o php5.3? qual versão é?

Comment: Acredito que [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/53409/91) explique o problema.

Comment: No hosweb é 5.3, na minha maquina o 7. atualizo pra qual versão no hostweb e se não der pra atualizar como posso corrigir todos "=>" sem mudar muita coisa no código?

Comment: O ideal é mudar a versão do php, o 5.3 foi lançando em 2009 ... quase de 10 atrás. caso não consiga mude o `['cnpj' => 'valor']` para `array('cnpj' => 'valor);`